HTML image doesn't show in iOS (Safari, Chrome)
I have an image in my Angular application: <img src="./logo.png">.
The image displays correctly on Windows Chrome and Android devices. However, on iOS devices (Mac, iPhone, iPad), the image is not shown, and a broken image icon appears instead.
When I directly enter the image URL in Chrome on iOS, the image loads correctly. After this, if I navigate back to the main application URL, the image displays properly in Chrome. However, this workaround doesn't work in Safari on iOS.
I've tried preloading the image in the index.html file of the application, but this did not resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.
I did try the <link rel="preload" ... as="image"> without any differents results.

can you upload that part of code on stackblitz?

There might multiple reasons, most likely some security reasons, maybe smth like wrong mime type, origin, or some other meta data of the img or its source.
Anyway, because in other browsers it works, meaning that the image itself is downloadable, you might try to convert the image to base64 and then use this value as  the image src.
It can be smth like this:
async function convertImageToBase64(imageUrl: string): Promise<string> {
  const response = await fetch(imageUrl);
  const blob = await response.blob();

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });
}

const base64ImageSrc = await convertImageToBase64('https://example.com/image.jpg')

